# Elementary question on HPF

Tags: analog

I was having some trouble understanding differentiator circuit. The output equation is -RC dv<sub>in</sub>/dt

Consider input as a ramp wave with the frequency way less than the reciprocal of the RC time constant. The output is clearly a square wave. I need clarity on how does the circuit evaluate output for dv<sub>in</sub>/dt. What is the value of dt does it consider? Does dt refer to the period of the triangle wave?

Comment: Please show us a schematic of the circuit in question.

Comment: "*Does dt refer to the period of the triangle wave?*" What triangle wave? I fixed some missing punctuation and added subscripts to your equation. Please check that I have conveyed your meaning correctly.

Comment: Circuit is simple CR with RC time constant is about 1ms. Input to the circuit is a triangle or rather sawtooth with peak voltage of 1V and frequency of 10Hz. In this context, what is the value of dt?

Comment: _Does dt refer to the period of the triangle wave?_  No. _dt_ is the change in time not the time itself.  _What is the value of dt does it consider?_  It does not consider _dt_ per se. It is concerned with the rate of change of the input voltage which is what _dv/dt_ is.

Comment: ok. got it. For a sawtooth wave, slope is constant at all instances of dt. in this case it is 10. I got confused when applying a sine wave. I was wondering how the slope is maximum at zero crossings?